# Cannot mention users in group chat created via Graph API on Android

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams, microsoft-graph-teams

I use Graph API to create new group chat. Request endpoint and body are the same as described in Create Chat Graph API docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/chat-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#request-1

```
POST https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/chats
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "chatType": "group",
  "topic": "Group chat title",
  "members": [
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('8c0a1a67-50ce-4114-bb6c-da9c5dbcf6ca')"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('82fe7758-5bb3-4f0d-a43f-e555fd399c6f')"
    },
    {
      "@odata.type": "#microsoft.graph.aadUserConversationMember",
      "roles": ["owner"],
      "user@odata.bind": "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users('3626a173-f2bc-4883-bcf7-01514c3bfb82')"
    }
  ]
}
```

Group chat is created successfully, all members are resent.

I have the same user logged in on Windows, iOS and Android Teams clients. So the issue is:

- on Windows Teams I can mention anybody in this chat
- on iOS Teams I can mention anybody in this chat
- on Android Teams I **cannot** mention anybody in this chat

Is it a known issue? I searched for similar questions in Microsoft Answers, in Teams Known Issues, in Teams Known Issues and in Google generally - and found no solution to fix the bug.
I need users to have an ability to mention someone in the chat created via Graph API.

I tested this behaviour on several Android devices - all my colleagues have different Android devices and experience this issue too. My own Android and Teams versions:

- Android 13
- Teams 1416/1.0.0.2023203702/1108

---

**UPDATE 1:**

I investigated more, the issue is still here, sometimes in newly created chat I can mention someone and sometimes not. I created about 30 group chats one by one and tried to mention users in each of them - only about 10 of them gave me this ability.
All I did is:

1. Enter Teams on my Android device, "Chats" tab and wait.
2. Send POST request to create a new group chat with 2 participants (only 2 because in my case I did not want many users to be involved into testing).
3. On my Android device enter newly created chat in Teams.
4. Enter "@" character and see if I can mention someone or not.
5. Repeat (1-4) many times to gather some statistics.

Here few screenshots of my different chats: https://imgur.com/a/EAkSdFA

Firstly I thought that the issue occurs because I enter newly created chat too fast. Then I started to wait for some time (up to 1 minute) before entering the chat - this also did not help.

---

**UPDATE 2:**

When I create chat manually, I CAN mention users. But another issue on Android Teams that I cannot invite any BOT just by mention. When I type @ I see only list of users present in the chat (unlike desktop Teams where I can mention any bot from any group chat and the bot is automatically invited).
So I tried this:

1. Create group chat manually
2. Use Graph API to add bot to the chat
3. And only then I CAN mention this bot

However, this behaviour doesn't allow me to automate some business processes. I want to create chat via Graph API, then add bot to this chat via Graph API and so users can quickly continue work normally in this chat.

And back to the topic I stuck with the issue when automatically created chat (via Graph API) sometimes works not as usual chat with broken mentions logic.

Comment: We tried this at our end and we are able to @mention users in Android as well. We tested this in OnePlus 9R device. Created a group chat - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sm5nS.png. Able to mention users in Android - https://i.stack.imgur.com/KAKUm.jpg. We were able to mention users using Graph as well and mention is reflecting properly in Android. Please let us know if you are doing it differently? Are all the users who face this issue from same tenant?

Comment: Did you get a chance to look into above comment?

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response!
I added more investigation info to the post. It was too long just for a comment. Seems like my issue reproduces simultaneously, but the most of the cases still fail.

Comment: We will check this internally with engineering team and get back to you.

Comment: Could you please confirm if this behavior is same for group chat created by Graph vs Manually?

Comment: Sorry for the long response. As my comment is too long I edited post with the requested info (UPDATE 2).

Comment: So just to confirm, creating group chat, adding bot via Graph works fine but issue is only when you create group chat manually?

Comment: The issue is here: using Graph API for group chat creation & people inviting sometimes breaks mentioning logic in this chat in Android Teams. Another scenario, just inconvinience: manually all works fine except the Android limitation to mention bot which is outside current group chat.

Comment: @Meghana-MSFT hi, any updates? Or maybe you need more info?